# Error when opening and closing an SSLSocket w/o writing any data

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

A simple server

```
listen = getServer();
Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Listening to "+listen.toString());
SSLSocket client = (SSLSocket)listen.accept();
// adding this line fixes everything - client.write(42);
client.close();
```

and a simple client

```
SocketFactory sockMaker = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
Socket server = sockMaker.createSocket("localhost", 1443);
int retval = server.getInputStream().read();
assert retval == -1;
server.close();
```

If I don't write anything to the SSL Socket, an exception is thrown in the client side:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException:\
  Received close_notify during handshake
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
```

I don't see why is that. Does the SSL/TLS specification requires you to write things into the socket?

See the [full example](https://github.com/elazarl/EmptyJavaSSL).

Comment: Your naming convention is a bit confusing regarding what the `client` and `server` sockets are. In addition, the client code is in your `SSLNullServer` directory on GitHub and your server code is in your `SSLNullClient` directory.

Comment: @Bruno, your points are valid, my bad. About naming convention, `Socket client` should be `Socket toClient` then it makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to write anything into the socket as such, but if you close it straight away, it will generate a `close_notify` alert (although it's called "alert", it's part of the normal way of closing a TLS/SSL socket).

In addition, SSL/TLS sockets are designed to behave "almost" like normal TCP sockets, but there are details where they don't (and can't) because of the way SSL/TLS works.
In particular, at the beginning of an SSL/TLS connection, the SSL/TLS handshake takes place, which involves a number of read/writes from each side, before sending any application data.

The [documentation for SSLSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) says:

> The initial handshake on this
> connection can be initiated in one of
> three ways:
>
> - calling `startHandshake` which explicitly begins handshakes, or
> - any attempt to read or write application data on this socket causes an implicit handshake, or
> - a call to `getSession` tries to set up a session if there is no currently
>   valid session, and an implicit
>   handshake is done.

Essentially, the `getInputStream().read()` by the client in your example initiates the handshake, which causes the server to proceed with `accept()` <strike>and perform the handshake on its side</strike>. However, since you close it (normally, but immediately) on the server side, you don't even let any time for the handshake to complete. Hence the `close_notify` is sent during the handshake, which causes the exception you get. Had you tried to read or write from the server side, the handshake would have at least completed.

**EDIT**: Following @EJP's comment, I should clarify what I meant:

- `createSocket("localhost", 1443)` on the client side establishes a connection and the server accepts it via `accept()`.
- `getInputStream().read()` on the client side makes it initiate the handshake. Thus, it sends a `ClientHello` TLS message to the server.
- Because the server uses `close()` straight after accepting the socket, it sends a `close_notify` alert. Because the server hasn't started to read/write, it hasn't started the handshake (and thus doesn't complete it).

Note that the purpose of [`ServerSocket.accept()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29), which `SSLServerSocket` implements, is to create an `SSLSocket`, not necessarily to do anything with it. The `SSLServerSocket` configures it, but proceeding with the handshake is out of scope. On the one hand, it might sound as making the `SSLSocket` behave more transparently like a normal TCP socket; on the other hand, it would imply reading from the underlying TCP stream, so it would have side-effects.
I haven't tried, but the `SSLSocket` created by the `SSLServerSocket` might still be configurable into a *client socket*. After all as the [RFC 2246 glossary](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#appendix-B) says:
*"client: The application entity that initiates a TLS connection to a server. This may or may not imply that the client initiated the underlying transport connection."* This would definitely have consequences regarding the transparency and when to do the handshake from the API point of view.

(Writing an API for SSL/TLS sockets that maps to the API of normal TCP sockets is a tricky exercise, and Java doesn't do too bad a job at it. The real "fun" starts with asynchronous TLS using `SSLEngine` and NIO channels. It gets even better considering that either side can initiate a new handshake at any time: the implications for the level above are undefined as far as TLS is concerned, which can lead to [awkward problems](http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-416).)

Comment: You could look into synchronizing using `addHandshakeCompletedListener` before closing on the server side (not sure if that's the goal of this experiment). At least that could allow you not to send that alert during the handshake.

Comment: In a single sentence the problem is, that `.close` does not imply a handshake. It means "close the socket, and if no handshake was done - too bad". I was expecting "close" to imply handshake as well.

Comment: @Bruno, a simpler fix is to force a handshake in the server side before closing the connection. (I'm trying to debug another exception in `SSLSocket`, and I tried a few simple cases).

Comment: `close` implies a `close_notify`, whether the handshake has completed or not. I'm not sure why it would make sense for `close` to imply a handshake: that's usually done to start a TLS connection or to re-negotiate some of its parameters; it's not particularly useful when you want to end the connection (which is the purpose of `close`).

Comment: @Bruno, I expect `SSLSocket` disallow breaking the protocol. If it is allowed to close a connection before the handshake - I expect `read` to return `-1` when `close_notified` is sent, even without handshake. If it is disallowed to send `close_notify` before handshake, indeed I expect `close` to imply handshake, in order not to break the protocol.

Comment: Sure, but if you remember my (now deleted) answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424998/properly-closing-sslsocket) (very similar to what GregS has now said too), you seem to be expecting SSL sockets to behave like normal TCP sockets. They almost do, but they don't: the handshaking/alerting can't always be synchronized in a way that looks natural to a normal read/write at the layer above. The problem you're trying to fix here (closing straight after accepting) is completely artificial anyway: don't expect these edge-cases to behave in a sensible, TCP-like way.

Comment: @Bruno let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1027/discussion-between-elazar-leibovich-and-bruno)

Comment: @Bruno the server had already done the accept() before the handshake starts. The server side is initiated by doing I/O just as the client side is.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is invalid. You are trying to read data that isn't sent. This is an application protocol error. All the statements in Bruno's answer apply as well. The client is trying to do a handshake; the server is trying to close the connection. Arguably the server close could initiate a handshake if it hasn't been done already, but it doesn't.

As you've noted, another workaround would be to call startHandshake() at either end.

Comment: "All the statements in Bruno's answer apply as well.": I've just edited my answer, so I'm not sure if you still agree with it...

Comment: @Bruno I agree with it even more now ;-)

Comment: First, the situation is definitely valid, since `read` should recognize `EOF`, so it's perfectly OK to do what I did, generally speaking. Second, as I told Bruno. if TLS allows you to send `close_notify` without a handshake, the client's `read` should return `-1`, and shouldn't throw (as protocol don't require an handshake), and if `TLS` require a handshake before `close_notify`, then `close` should complete the handshake before closing.

Comment: @Elazar, the semantics of `-1` on the `InputStream` can only become valid once the TLS connection has been established. If this example, you're closing the connection before this happens, so getting an exception should be expected. In addition, as I was saying in an [updated answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424998/properly-closing-sslsocket/6425509#6425509), don't rely too much on reading `-1`: you'll inevitably have to deal with exceptions too.

Comment: @Bruno, I perfectly agree with you wrote in the other answer. My problem here is the API, not with the protocol. What I'm saying is, that if you're hiding the handshake from the user - you should not have the abstraction leak this fact to the user as an exception. If the handshake should happen lazily without user's intervention, then you it should either happen upon connect (which makes sense actually), and not on first read, or have it happen automatically when using `close`, or at the very least document that `you must use the SSLSocket before closing it` and throw upon invalid `close`.