# How can I confirm a handshake was completed with SSL Sockets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, java-8

Here's some pseudocode

```
Client:
    boolean sent = false;
    byte[] message = new String("test").getBytes();

    send()
    {
        sent = sslSocket.sendMessage(message);

        if (sent)
            sslSocket.close();
    }
```

I'm writing tests that should be fairly quick. Once the `Client` successfully sends a message, it should close immediately. In my tests, the `Client` returns `sent == true`, so the socket closes. However, the `Server` is throwing a `received close_notify during handshake` exception. This exception does not happen when I use `Thread.sleep(200)` right before closing the `Client`.

Our sockets are our own abstractions and wrappers for Java's sockets. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534128/error-when-opening-and-closing-an-sslsocket-w-o-writing-any-data) post, I have to assume that the Server has not completed the handshake, but the `Client` has? Why else would `sent` return `true`? I can't confirm that the message actually HAS been received by the `Server`, however, because the exception is thrown immediately. I only have `Client` `sent` boolean to rely on.

So my question is **how can I confirm the handshake was completed?**

Thank you for the help, and sorry for any ambiguity! I can clear any confusions!

Comment: What class is `sslSocket`? [SSLSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) does not appear to have a `sendMessage` method. The reason `sent` would be true is because `sendMessage` returns `true`, there's a reason why it returns that however I can't find it yet (since I'm not sure what `sslSocket` is).

Comment: It's our own method and abstracts Java Sockets. I'm fairly new to the code and can't really see what it does exactly. Ignoring the code, is it possible for a client to send a message to the server before a handshake is completed? I'm new to SSL too and don't entirely understand how that could work

Answer (score 1):

@Mark brought up a good point about the `sendMessage()` method. I looked into it more, and it doesn't return `true` when the message has been sent, but returns when the message has been placed on an output queue. So it turns out the message probably was never actually sent. Documentation was incorrect.

Thus, the handshake was never actually complete and `sent` was a lie because the connection was never fully open.

Thank you @Mark!