# are there some api in java equals to openSSL?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

are there some APIs in java that equals to OpenSSL APIs such as  `ssl_accept()`,`SSL_connect,ssl_read()`,`ssl_write()` and so on ?

thanks.

Comment: See also [Is it possible to change plain socket to SSLSocket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559859/is-it-possible-to-change-plain-socket-to-sslsocket). (sodarfish knows this already, this is more for later visitors.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less the same answer as the one I posted to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559859/is-it-possible-to-change-plain-socket-to-sslsocket/6564086#6564086).

If you turn a `Socket` into an `SSLSocket` using [`SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket, String, int, boolean)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.Socket,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29), you can still turn it into a server-side `SSLSocket` using [`SSLSocket.setUseClientMode(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setUseClientMode%28boolean%29), as long as you haven't started to read/write using the I/O streams of the `SSLSocket` (this would trigger the handshake at you can't change the mode after that).

Alternatively, you can use [`SSLEngine`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html). To be honest, it tends to be harder to use. You may find examples in the SSL implementations of [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org/), [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) and [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) (in NIO mode).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)?

Comment: no..  ssl_accept() api of openssl can bind an ssl context on an existed plain socket, so i want to know how to do that with java ? thanks.

Comment: @solarfish - why don't you just do it the Java way?

Comment: @sodarfish The **See Also:** section of the JavaDoc is your friend ;)  [SSLSocketFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html)

Comment: actually, i want to handle ssl and non-ssl connections on the same port, but SSLServerSocket can only handle ssl connections.  OpenSSL can do that ,so i wonder if java can do that ?

Comment: What I was pointing you to was the SSLSocketFactory, which has a method to convert an existing, non-SSL socket to SSL. You might find it helpful to go through the [Java Networking Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html) to get a feel for how Java handles socket programming in general.

Comment: thansk for your relply. I'v tried the createSocket method out, but its used to create a client side ssl socket , what i want is to change an existing socket which is created by server.accept() method to an SSLSocket. is that possible ?

Comment: @sodarfish yes, see Bruno's reply.