# How write in SSLSocket before handshake?

Tags: java, ssl, networking, https

```
    Socket fromServer = new Socket("host", 443);

    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(fromServer, null, true);
    sslsocket.setUseClientMode(true);
```

i try it, but get "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error"

If i use SSLSocket directly it work (factory.createSocket("host", 443);)

add:
i need add custom header BEFORE handshake, for implement custom protocol

add2:
Code works! it my fail, i test on server with SNI

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Fildor, add custom header for custom protocol

Comment: Look here: http://blog.trifork.com/2009/11/10/securing-connections-with-tls/

Comment: Fildor, it for server. I try use for client

Comment: You have to do it in Client **and** Server anyway. Both sides must switch to TLS at the same time. The switching part should be actually the same for both.

Comment: Code works! it my fail, i test in server with SNI

Answer (score 3):

An SSLSocket transfers data within a TLS connection. A TLS connection need to be established before data can be transferred, i.e. the handshake must successfully complete. Thus it does not make sense to write to a SSLSocket before the handshake completed the same way it does not make sense to write to a TCP socket before the TCP connection got established.

> add: i need add custom header BEFORE handshake, for implement custom protocol

After this information got added the question makes more sense. It looks like you want to first exchange unencrypted data and then upgrade to TLS later like done for example in SMTP+STARTTLS. In this case you need to first establish a normal TCP connection and then later upgrade it to TLS. See [Is it possible to change plain socket to SSLSocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559859/is-it-possible-to-change-plain-socket-to-sslsocket) for how to do the latter part.

Comment: i know it. i need add custom header BEFORE handshake, for implement custom protocol

Comment: Well it does make sense if your protocol allows for safe **and** unsafe communication. If you want to handle both over the same port you can start naked and as soon as both parties have agreed on using SSL/TLS they can startTLS. An example would be SMTP ...

Comment: Fildor, that's right

Comment: @inter: I've updated the answer after you've updated the question.

Comment: thank, but pleas see my code, it like as code from your link. It not work actialy

Comment: @inter: since it works with immediate handshake but not with plain text before the handshake my guess is that the server simply does not like the plain data before but expects a TLS handshake. You cannot simply send data the server cannot handle.

Comment: it work, but i test it on server with SNI. my  fail.