# Getting SSLHandshakeException (Handshake failed) when calling SSLSocket#getInputStream

Tags: android, serversocket, sslsocketfactory

I'm testing a `SSLSocket` connection for a server running as `IntentService` I'm running on Android app. For that, I'm using [PacketSender](https://packetsender.com/) to send a SSL packet with data, where it was working when using Socket instead of `SSLSocket`.

When tring to receive data from PacketSender, the app manages to accept the connection, but throws an Exception (see below) when trying to call `getInputStream`:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb967c838: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100b60c1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:NO_SHARED_CIPHER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1085 0xac4e759f:0x00000000)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
... 7 more
```

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559859/is-it-possible-to-change-plain-socket-to-sslsocket) to try switching from plain `Socket` to `SSLSocket`.

**EDIT:** Tried implementing a self-signed certificate for the server app, but the error is persists.

```
private SSLContext createSSLContext(){
    try{
        byte[] der = SERVER_CERT.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream derInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(der);
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(derInputStream);
        String alias = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();

        // Create keystore and add to ssl context
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null);
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        kmf.init(trustStore, null);
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

        return sslContext;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does the server provide a certificate?

Comment: No, I tried following the cited answer. Also, I don't need a real certificate, because the validation is done a step before. Just need to enable SSL communication to encrypt the packet swap.

Comment: By my understanding you need a certificate since not having one makes the connection insecure and that's not enabled by using SSLSockets

Comment: Is there any way to create a temporary certificate to be used only during the communication between apps?

Comment: If you want to use SSL just create a certificate and added to the server, you can generate free SSL certificates with [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)