# boost::asio and async SSL stream: how to detect end of data/connection close?

Tags: ssl, boost-asio

I'm trying to make asio and SSL friends.
Everything going well, but one thing is causing inconvenience: how to
detect if peer close connection, and distinguish it from situation
when peer just take a short break in sending data, aiming to continue
it few seconds later?

- boost 1.48
- OpenSSL 1.0.0e
- Compiled to 32-bit code using VS10
- Working on W7 x64.

My confusion comes from the fact, that asio behaviour is different for
ordinary socket and SSL-stream.
If I use tcp::socket - I receive EOF error when peer close connection.
But for boost::asio::ssl::stream - it is
not the case. Instead, async_read_some returns 0 as bytes transfered,
and if I try to continue to read from SSL stream - returns short_error
( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html ).

So, the questions is: is it expected behaviour, or I misconfigure anything?

Client code  snippet:

```
class client
{
public:

    // bla-bla-bla-bla-bla ....
    //
   void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
   {
       if (!error)
       {
           socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(reply_, max_length),
               boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this,
               boost::asio::placeholders::error,
               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
       }
   }

   void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                   size_t bytes_transferred)
   {

       std::cout << "Bytes transfered: " << bytes_transferred << "\n";
       if (!error)
       {
           std::cout << "Reply: ";
           std::cout.write(reply_, bytes_transferred);
           std::cout << "\n";

           std::cout << "Reading...\n";
           socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(reply_, max_length),
               boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this,
               boost::asio::placeholders::error,
               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
       }
       else if (0 != bytes_transferred)
       {
           std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << ":" 
                     << error.value() <<  "\n";
       }
   }

private:
   boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
   boost::asio::streambuf request_;
   char reply_[max_length];
};
```

If we remove if (0 != bytes_transferred), we'll get "short read" :(.

If we'll use code as-ai, output will be something like this:

> Request is:
>
> GET / HTTP/1.0
>
> Cookie: Nama-nama=Vala-vala
>
> Bytes transfered: 1024
>
> Reply: HTTP/1.0 200 ok
>   Content-type: text/html
>
> ..... bla-bla-bla ....
>
> Reading...
>   Bytes transfered: 1024
>
> ..... bla-bla-bla ....
>   ..... bla-bla-bla ....
>
> Reading...
>   Bytes transfered: 482
>
> ..... bla-bla-bla ....
>
> Reading...
>
> Bytes transfered: 0

At the same time, if instead async_read_some  we write code, what for
ordinary socket will return EOF:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
    boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
    boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

then for SSL-socket we'll get 0 as bytes transfered, and then short_read.

I know that there is not way to detect disconnect in case if peer, for
example, was just unplugged from the network.
But how to detect explicit clean peer disconnect from situation when
peer just do not send data for a some time, but may be will do it
little bit later?

Or, may be I do not understant something?

WBR,
Andrey

*Some addentum:*
SSL/TLS has notation to inform other party about closing connection.
It close_notify alert. Also underlying TCP socket can be closed.

So, basically, my question is: why, in the same conditions (TCP socket was closed clearly) I receive EOF in case of tcp::socket, and do not receive anything  for boost::asio::ssl::stream.

Is it bug or asio feature?

Yet another addentum:
For some reasons asio didn't give me a EOF neither if SSL receive close_notify nor underlying TCP socket was closed.

Yes, I can detect dead connections by timeout.
But how can I detect properly closed SSL-connections? By receiving short_read?

Answer (score 16):

The `SSL_R_SHORT_READ` error is expected here. When the server initiates a clean shutdown with [`SSL_Shutdown`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html) this sends the close notify shutdown alert to the client. The Asio implementation maps this into an `SSL_R_SHORT_READ` error with the category of `error::get_ssl_category()`. It does this by detecting if the peer has initiated shutdown via [`SSL_get_shutdown`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_set_shutdown.html).

This can be seen by inspecting `asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp` header and specifically the function `engine::map_error_code(boost::system::error_code&)`.

I believe the ssl implementation was rewritten in boost 1.47, so earlier versions have potentially different behavior.

Comment: I don't see a short read. I see this: If the remote host calls shutdown then the local host's read will complete with eof. If both hosts call shutdown then the calls to shutdown will complete with eof. These are ssl::stream shutdowns, not TCP/IP shutdown. I have written a test that confirms this.

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested in these discussions:

- [how to detect a TCP socket disconnection (with c berkeley socket)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404085/372643)
- [Properly closing SSLSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425509/372643)

Essentially, the fact that you get an EOF sometimes (even most of the time) when the remote party disconnects a plain TCP socket is just luck. You can't rely on it in the general case, since it's not possibly to distinguish between an inactive socket and a socket closed abruptly without writing to it.

You need to define some delimiters, at the application protocol level, to know when to stop reading.
In HTTP, this is done either via the blank line that ends the header (for the header), the `Content-Length` header that defines the body length, or the [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) delimiters when the body length isn't known in advance.

Comment: SSL/TLS has notation to inform other party about closing connection.
It close_notify alert. Also underlying TCP socket being closed.

So, basically, my question was: why, in the same conditions (TCP socket was closed clearly) I receive EOF in case of tcp::socket, and do not receive anything  for boost::asio::ssl::stream.

Is it bug or feature?

Comment: Sure, `close_notify` is for clean closures, that won't help you to detect the bad ones. I don't know much about `boost::asio::ssl::stream`, but my guess is that you're doing asynchronous operations and SSL/TLS closure will cause problems with asynchronous operations (see "Properly closing SSLSocket" link above). It might explain a slightly different behaviour. Either way, it doesn't really matter. It wouldn't be a bug that needs fixing, since it's just not the correct way of finding out when to stop reading from a stream/socket.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure what you meant by "*It close_notify alert. Also underlying TCP socket being closed.*", but a TLS closure alert doesn't not imply that the underlying TCP socket must be closed.

Comment: I'm working on SSL level.
So I would expect to get an EOF if peer send close_notify.
And of cource I would expect to get an EOF if underlying TCP socket was closed.
But it is not the case!
Ok, dead SSL-connections can be detected via timeouts. But what about properly finished/closed? asio didn't give me anything, except short_read. What is not really suitable in this case, from common sence point of view. :(

Comment: Since you can't distinguish between a remote party that's "dead" or not sending anything, detecting proper closures of TCP/TLS isn't generally useful: knowing when to stop reading is up to the app. layer. Presumably, asio throws an except. in case of truncation attack (i.e. TCP closure w/o TLS `close_notify`). Once you've read what you were meant to read (at the HTTP layer here), presence/absence of exception will indicate problems. Knowing whether there's a proper closure is barely relevant. If it occurs in the middle of an HTTP (or other application) message, you'll have a problem anyway.