# SocketIo EngineIOException cause: SSLException

Tags: android, exception, socket.io

I get this exception on Android using SocketIo, everytime when internet gets disconnected (I turn off wifi). I cant find the reason, please help :

[image]

Comment: And what, exactly, is the question?

Comment: how to get rid of this exception. what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is exception is to be expected any time an `SSLSocket` read fails due to an unavailable network. Socket.IO clients may safely ignore it.

As you might expect, disabling a network while you are using it causes I/O errors. In Java, this produces an `IOException` of one kind or another. If you had been using "normal" sockets, this would have been a `SocketException`, and you would have seen the same sort of message ("software caused connection abort"). Since, in this case, you are using an HTTPS connection, the `IOException` is an `SSLException` (which wraps the error encountered by the lower-level TCP socket).

Any `IOExceptions` thrown by the TCP socket will cause `SSLExceptions` on the `SSLSocket`, at least until such time as the `SSLSocket` is [properly closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424998/properly-closing-sslsocket).

Comment: Cant ignore this. When i get this exception, my socket shuts down and i need to re-initiate and connect this socket.

Comment: Yes, it might not've been clear from my answer, but this socket is definitely done; the connection is over. After all, you have removed the network! I simply meant that you didn't have to take any special action; it's like any other `IOException` received on a socket. To continue transferring data, you will have to re-establish the connection; there is no getting around that. Note that Socket.IO does this for you, automatically, by default (ref. `IO.Options.reconnection`). If you are having problems with this, you should edit your question to clarify.