# Plaintext Connection

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I am creating a simple HTTPS connection and returning a response

```
URL google = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)google.openConnection();
System.out.println( "Response: " + connection.getResponseCode());
```

This works fine and I receive a 200 response (I have all the keystores and truststores etc. defined)

I then proxy the request through a Jetty server by using https.proxyPort=8443 and https.proxyHost-localhost

The server has connectors that look like this:

```
Server server = new Server();
SelectChannelConnector connector0 = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector0.setPort(8080);
SslSelectChannelConnector sslConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();
sslConnector.setPort(8443);
SslContextFactory cf = sslConnector.getSslContextFactory();
cf.setKeyStorePath(keyStoreHome);
cf.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);
cf.setTrustStore(trustStoreHome);
cf.setTrustStorePassword(trustStorePassword);
cf.setCertAlias("jetty");
server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {connector0, sslConnector});
server.setHandler(new HelloHandler());
server.start();
server.join();
```

Which gives me the error below:

```
DEBUG: org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - created SCEP@33589e56{l(/127.0.0.1:62348)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8443),d=false,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{SslConnection@7f033a6f SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=-1/-1/-1 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@26c623af,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}}
DEBUG: org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@7f033a6f SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=180/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@26c623af,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=180/180 flushed=0/0
DEBUG: org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - SCEP@33589e56{l(/127.0.0.1:62348)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8443),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0r}-{SslConnection@7f033a6f SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=180/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@26c623af,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(EngineInputRecord.java:152)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:806)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:721)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.unwrap(SslConnection.java:519)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.process(SslConnection.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.access$900(SslConnection.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection$SslEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:661)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1030)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:620)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
DEBUG: org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@33589e56{l(/127.0.0.1:62348)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8443),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0!}-{SslConnection@7f033a6f SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=180/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@26c623af,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}}
DEBUG: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Can anybody please tell me what might be wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it the exception is occurring when the proxy is connecting the HTTP - 8080 and HTTPS - 8443. Does JETTY do decryption between those ports because if not the exception is about the 8080 being plain text.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396178/372643).

When you use `https.proxyPort=8443` and `https.proxyHost=localhost`, the connection between your client and the proxy host/port isn't done using SSL/TLS, but in plain text HTTP. The client then sends the proxy a `CONNECT` request with the target host name (and this is way you get this "plain text" exception).

Then, the proxy makes a request to that target server and establishes a tunnel that relays all the raw traffic back and forth. From the client's point of view (`HttpsUrlConnection`), the socket that is connected to the proxy is upgraded to SSL/TLS (i.e. it initiate an handshake, which is relayed to the target server via that tunnel.

There aren't many clients that also support having the connection between the client and the proxy itself using HTTPS. This isn't generally very useful, since an attacker could only see the host name and port anyway.