# Handle HTTPS Tunnling using java

Tags: java, http, proxy, connect

I am trying to build a proxy server and recently I am working on https. As specified in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396104/sslhttpserroronmycustomproxyserver/6396178#6396178). I've tried to tunnel Connect request. My Code is as:

```
private boolean handleConnect(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse response){
    String uri=req.getRequestURI();
    String port="";
    String host="";
    int c=uri.indexOf(":");
    if (c >= 0){
        port = uri.substring(c + 1);
        host = uri.substring(0,c);
        if (host.indexOf('/') > 0)
            host = host.substring(host.indexOf('/') + 1);
    }
    // Make Asyncronous connection
    try{
        InetSocketAddress inetAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host,Integer.parseInt(port));
        {
            InputStream in=req.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out=response.getOutputStream();
            if(true){
                Socket sock=new Socket(host,Integer.parseInt(port));
                IO.copy(in, sock.getOutputStream());
                IO.copy(sock.getInputStream(), out);
                if(!sock.getKeepAlive()){
                    sock.close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The code results `java.net.UnknownHostException: google.com.np` for `https://google.com.np` and Timeouts for `https://Facebook.com` . Why is that ?? 
Please suggest best way to tunnel Connect HTTP request.

Comment: Why are you closing the socket if keepalive isn't set? Why not *set* it for example? And even if you can't set it you can still service the request.

Comment: I dont know the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UnknownHostException is due either to a non-existent host or a misconfigured DNS, and your connect timeout to a network connectivity problem, neither of which are on-topic here, but you can't really write a proper proxy this way. You need to start two threads per connection, one to copy bytes in each direction.